# Symbols in XML attributes

Tags: xml

Can i use symbol ':' in xml attributes like

```
<tag1 attribute1:meaning1="true">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `:` is used to include a namespace (which is part of the fully qualified name of the attribute) before the local name of the node.

So, yes it is allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use ":" symbol in xml attributes

like

img src="http://----" />

Comment: the question is about using ":" in the attributes name, not the content.